ReactJS Service Worker Cache issue
I am facing issue in reactJS build, the service worker is making the cache and the cache files are available in  "Cache Storage" however when fetching back it doesn't fetch. Thanks in advance. And more thing which i notice is in 'Cache Storage' when i click .map file it shows the code however when i click.js file it shows "No network manager for request" and on index.html file 'You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.' I check in other devices however still not running in offline
const CACHE_NAME = 'appV1';

// Fetch and parse the asset-manifest file
async function getFilesToCache() {
  try {
    const response = await fetch('/asset-manifest.json');
    const manifest = await response.json();
    // Extract file paths from the manifest
    const files = Object.values(manifest.files);
    // Add root HTML and fallback page
    files.push('/index.html');
    // files.push('/offline.html');
    // Remove duplicate entries
    return Array.from(new Set(files));
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Failed to fetch asset manifest:', error);
    return [];
  }
}

self.addEventListener('install', (event) => {
  console.log('Service Worker: Installing...');
  event.waitUntil(
    getFilesToCache().then( async (filesToCache) => {
      return caches.open(CACHE_NAME).then((cache) => {
        console.log('Service Worker: Caching files');
        return cache.addAll(filesToCache);
      });
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.error('Service Worker: Caching failed:', error);
    })
  );
});

self.addEventListener('activate', (event) => {
  console.log('Service Worker: Activating...');
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.keys().then((cacheNames) => {
      return Promise.all(
        cacheNames.map((cacheName) => {
          if (cacheName !== CACHE_NAME) {
            console.log('Service Worker: Removing old cache', cacheName);
            return caches.delete(cacheName);
          }
        })
      );
    })
  );
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
    console.log('Service Worker: Fetching', event.request.url);
  
    event.respondWith(
      caches.match(event.request)
        .then((cachedResponse) => {
          if (cachedResponse) {
            console.log('Service Worker: Found in cache:', event.request.url);
            return cachedResponse;
          }
  
          console.log('Service Worker: Not found in cache, fetching from network:', event.request.url);
          return fetch(event.request)
            .then((networkResponse) => {
              // Optionally cache new responses
              // caches.open(CACHE_NAME).then((cache) => cache.put(event.request, networkResponse.clone()));
              console.log('Service Worker: Network response:', event.request.url);
              return networkResponse;
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              // Handle the network request failure
              console.log('Service Worker: Network request failed, returning fallback response');
              return new Response('No internet connection. Please check your connection and try again.', {
                status: 503,  // Service Unavailable
                statusText: 'Service Unavailable'
              });
            });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error('Service Worker: Fetch handling failed:', error);
          return new Response('An error occurred while fetching the resource.', {
            status: 500,  // Internal Server Error
            statusText: 'Internal Server Error'
          });
        })
    );
  });
  

Need the Application to work offline
